# Make a variable globally readable, but only from the file writable

Tags: scala

I want to have a `var` in a singleton object that I want to read from everywhere but only write into it from another singleton object (which is a companion object, but I don't think it matters here). Thus I put both objects into one file `MyClass` and made the `var` private but opened it up to the scope of the file with `private[MyClass]`.

As a toy example: Everything is in the same file "MyClass.scala":

```
object OtherObject {
    private[MyClass] var myvar = 0.0
    def variable = myvar
}
object MyClass{
    def setmyvar(myvar: Double): Unit = {
        OtherObject.myvar = 2.0
    }
}
class MyClass { ... }
```

This does not work however. I get the error "MyClass is not an enclosing class". How can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be not a companion object. You can have [companion of class and object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html), both sharing the same name. Thus the error.

Putting that aside, you can achieve that what you asked for, by having both objects in the same package and limiting access with private to that package, or wrapping those objects with another one, and setting appropriate private modifier, like here:

```
object MyWrapper {
    object OtherObject {
        private[MyWrapper] var myvar = 0.0
        def variable = myvar
    }
    object MyClass{
        def setmyvar(myvar: Double): Unit = {
            OtherObject.myvar = myvar
        }
    }
}
```

And then it works:

```
scala> MyWrapper.OtherObject.variable
res3: Double = 0.0
scala> MyWrapper.MyClass.setmyvar(3)
scala> MyWrapper.OtherObject.variable
res5: Double = 3.0
```

although it isn't especially elegant piece of code

Comment: No it is not elegant. I would say the next higher step in the hierarchy from the view of the object would be the file not the package (which is a directory). So am I not able to restrict to the file?

Comment: @Make42 you are confusing things. There is no 1-1 mapping between classes/packages and files/directories in Scala. Scala is pretty flexible in terms of code organization. So to achieve this what you asked for, you should probably put them into single package, and set your var private within this package.

Answer (score 1):

> but opened it up to the scope of the file

A file doesn't define a scope in Scala, period. So you can't make something writable only within the same file.

(There are actually three cases where files are relevant to scope that I can think of:

1. Top-level package statements have the rest of the entire file as their scope.
2. A class and an object with the same name are only companions if they are in the same file.
3. `sealed` traits or classes can only be extended in the same file.

None of them are useful for your question.)

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

A companion object must be defined inside the same source file as the class. **Both should have same name. one should be class and another should be object type. Then only we can call it as companion.**

```
object MyClass {
    private[MyClass] var myvar = 0.0
    def variable = myvar
}
class MyClass{
    def setmyvar(myvar: Double): Unit = {
        // your logic 
    }
}
```

http://daily-scala.blogspot.in/2009/09/companion-object.html

Comment: Thank you, but `class MyClass` is not related to my question.

Comment: All I tried to mean is , what you have created is not companien object.

Comment: What I meant to program is: `object MyClass` is the companion object to `class MyClass`. `object MyObject` is unrelated and not a companion object. I will rename it, to make this clear.